# thread fails to start if wx.app.mainloop isn't called from the main module

Tags: python, multithreading, wxpython

I'm hoping someone can explain this behavior to me. If I import a module that starts a wxpython interface, threads are unable to start until after the app.MainLoop() ends. Simplest example:

simple_app.py

```
import wx
from threading import Thread

def test():
    from time import sleep
    while 1:
        print("thread still running")
        sleep(2)

app = wx.App() 
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'simple.py')
frame.Show()
thread = Thread(target=test)
thread.setDaemon(True)
thread.start()
app.MainLoop()
```

main.py

```
import simple_app
```

If you run simple_app.py by itself it works fine, if you run main.py the thread never starts... Why? I have a feeling it has to do with the thread being unable to secure a lock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The second thread in `simple_app.py` is trying to import the `time` module while an import is already running, which leads to deadlock when `simple_app` is being imported from the main module. Because imports acquire interpreter's import lock for the current thread while importing a module. It has been [documented](https://docs.python.org/2/library/threading.html#importing-in-threaded-code).

Threads in the main module can import other modules that's why running `simple_app.py` as main module works. Moving `from time import sleep` to module level in `simple_app.py` solves the problem.

Running the following code helps better understand the problem;

my_time.py
`from time import sleep`

simple_app.py

```
import imp
import sys
from threading import Thread
from time import sleep

import wx

class MyFinder(object):
    def __init__(self):
        print('MyFinder initializing')
        if imp.lock_held():
            while imp.lock_held():
                print('import lock held')
                sleep(2)
            print('import lock released')
        else:
            print('import lock is not held')

    def find_module(self, module, package=None):
        print('MyFinder.find_module called with module name "{}", pakcage name "{}"'.format(module, package))
        return None


def test():
    sys.meta_path.append(MyFinder())
    from my_time import sleep
    count = 0
    while True:
        print("{} thread still running".format(count))
        count += 1
        sleep(2)


app = wx.App()
frame = wx.Frame(None, -1, 'simple.py')
frame.Show()
thread = Thread(target=test)
thread.setDaemon(True)
thread.start()
app.MainLoop()
```

Comment: This is a very useful and informed answer. Really helps illustrate the internals of what's going on. Thanks.

Comment: Think this answer nails it and would earn to be marked as accepted answer and to get the bounty.

Answer (score 1):

This was a quite interesting problem. The issue at hand was not quite obvious (at least to me).

The last line of *simple_app.py* blocks until `frame` is closed/destroyed. Therefore if started from *main.py* the import will finish only (and show output from print), when the frame is closed.

Try the following instead (normally you would structure your program better to start/stop the app where you need it):

In *simple_app.py* change last line to:

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.MainLoop()
```

In *main.py*

```
import wx
import simple_app
app = wx.GetApp()
app.MainLoop()
```

I can not tell you why exactly there is a difference on running directly and on importing (running directly shows the result of print, but importing does not).

Comment: This is a good solution to the problem. I might offer a bounty for the question to see if I can get anyone to explain why this occurs. What's weird is that no matter where you put the thread it always hangs until MainLoop ends. Sometimes the thread will even print once before freezing. Oddly unpredictable

Comment: For me (Python 2.7/wxPython3.0 classic) the behaviour is always the same: Your example blocks on ``app.MainLoop()`` during the import (the import never gets finished). Only after the frame is closed, it will finalize the import and finalize the *main.py* script. And only then the thread will get started and squeeze off the first print, and then it dies immediately (because it is a daemon thread).